# My for loop breaks and repeats the output over and over

Tags: python, list, for-loop

My code is a WW2 fact machine and for example if you input "1939" the code should print "start of war". If you input a keyword like "Dunkirk" it should work the same way and print the corresponding index from the facts list. But right now if I were to type 1939 or any input in fact, it will print the same output over and over.

```
#Keyword facts
facts = ["start of war","Germany invades Norway + Denmark","USA declares war against 
Japanese","USA begins raiding Japanese islands","Allies invade Scilly and put 
Mussolini out of power","Battle of Normandy","May 8th 1945 Germany surrendered"]

factsK = ["The deadliest battle in the War, Germany and its allies fought the soviets 
for the city with extreme close quarters combat and direct air raids on civilians", 
"Was a German military tactic calculated to create psychological shock and resultant 
disorganization in enemy forces through the employment of surprise, speed, and 
superiority","The allies were losing the battle of France and were pushed to the port 
of Dunkirk by the Germans. The Germans halted their push for three days which allowed 
allies to organize a retreat, more than 330,000 Allied troops were rescued","In 1941, 
Just before that Sunday morning, hundreds of Japanese fighter planes descended on the 
base, where they managed to destroy or damage nearly 20 American naval vessels, 300 
airplanes, and 2,400 Americans, Japan was hoping to cripple the American fleet before 
they entered the war. The USA declared war the day after","Codenamed Operation 
Overlord, the battle began on June 6, 1944, also known as D-Day, when some 156,000 
American, British and Canadian forces landed on five beaches along a 50 mile stretch 
of the heavily fortified coast of France’s Normandy region, creating a second 
front.D-Day was known as the beginning of the end of the War.","The liberation of 
Paris occured in 1944 where French Liberation forces staged an uprising against the 
Germans while the Americans were quickly approaching. Once the American army arrived 
in the city the German Garrison commander Dietrich von Choltitz, surrendered to the 
French allowing them to have the city again","The battle of Berlin occured in 1945 
and was one of the last major offensives in the war. The Soviets successfully 
encircled the city, The germans refused to surrender, but the Soviets were too 
overpowering for the remaining troops. Hitler ended up commiting suicide and the 
remaining German troops were captured or killed. The Nazis officially surendered a 
week later on May 9th"]

User = input(("Keyword or date "))

Dates = ["1939","1940","1941","1942","1943","1944","1945"]

Keywords =["Stalingrad","Blitz","Dunkirk","Pearl Harbor","D-Day","Paris","Berlin"]

#need "iteration" and "selection from list"
for D in Dates:
  for K in Keywords:
    if D == User:
         print(facts[Dates.index(D)])
    elif K == User:
        print(factsK[Keywords.index(K)])
```

Comment: This seems like it would be better to store in dictionaries, then you can use dates or keywords as keys to access the facts or factsk

Answer (score 1):

Nested loops (only) make sense if you want to examine all combinations of your two loop variables. Indeed, the reason your current code prints multiple times is that it finds and prints every combination of keyword and date where either of them matches.

A really minimal fix would be to `break` out of the loops when you find a match, but as explained above, you really should not use nested loops here. Instead, perhaps loop over years, then if you didn't find a match there, loop over keywords.

However, a much better fix still is to use dictionaries as your data structure. Then you don't need loops at all.

```
years = {
    "1939": "start of war",
    "1940": "Germany invades Norway + Denmark",
    "1941": "USA declares war against Japan",
    "1942": "USA begins raiding Japanese islands",
    "1943": "Allies invade Scilly and put Mussolini out of power",
    "1944": "Battle of Normandy",
    "1945": "May 8th 1945 Germany surrendered"
}

keywords = {
    "Stalingrad": "The deadliest battle in the War, Germany and its allies fought the Soviets for the city with extreme close quarters combat and direct air raids on civilians",
    "Blitz": "A German military tactic calculated to create psychological shock and resultant disorganization in enemy forces through the employment of surprise, speed, and superiority",
    "Dunkirk": "The allies were losing the battle of France and were pushed to the port of Dunkirk by the Germans. The Germans halted their push for three days which allowed allies to organize a retreat, more than 330,000 Allied troops were rescued",
    "Pearl Harbor": "In 1941, just before that Sunday morning, hundreds of Japanese fighter planes descended on the base, where they managed to destroy or damage nearly 20 American naval vessels, 300 airplanes, and 2,400 Americans, Japan was hoping to cripple the American fleet before they entered the war. The USA declared war the day after",
    "D-Day": "Codenamed Operation Overlord, the battle began on June 6, 1944, also known as D-Day, when some 156,000 American, British and Canadian forces landed on five beaches along a 50 mile stretch of the heavily fortified coast of France’s Normandy region, creating a second front. D-Day was known as the beginning of the end of the War.",
    "Paris": "The liberation of Paris occurred in 1944 where French Liberation forces staged an uprising against the Germans while the Americans were quickly approaching. Once the American army arrived in the city, the German Garrison commander, Dietrich von Choltitz, surrendered to the French, allowing them to have the city again",
    "Berlin": "The battle of Berlin occurred in 1945 and was one of the last major offensives in the war. The Soviets successfully encircled the city, The germans refused to surrender, but the Soviets were too overpowering for the remaining troops. Hitler ended up commiting suicide and the remaining German troops were captured or killed. The Nazis officially surrendered a week later on May 9th"
}

choice = input("Keyword or date ")

if choice in years:
    print(years[choice])
elif choice in keywords:
    print(keywords[choice])
```

There's no reason to keep two separate dictionaries, really; as long as the keys are unique, you could simplify this still by combining them.

Comment: I also fixed a few typos in your text, though probably not all of them.